# How to backup twice in a day?

Tags: powershell, backup

I should  backup DHCP but I want to get twice in a day, at time 16:00 and 17:00. I made a scheduled job for 16:00 but I couldn't add other for other hour.

```
Register-ScheduleJob –Name “DHCPyedek” –FilePath “c:\powershell\scripts\dhcpYedek.ps1” –Trigger @{Frequency=”Daily”; At=”16:00PM”}
```

Comment: why not? are you using the same name maybe?

Comment: What happens when you try? Are you getting an error? Can you show us the code you used for the other hour?

Comment: I tried add new hour too like that At=”16:00PM”,"17:00pM"} etc. but i think there is a command for it i cant find

Comment: I found that "repetition" Do you know How can I use it?

Comment: I would recommend creating a task with 2 daily triggers.

Comment: I solved so   Register-ScheduleJob –Name “DHCPyedek” –FilePath “c:\powershell\scripts\dhcpYedek.ps1” –Trigger @{Frequency=”Daily”; At=”16:00PM”},Trigger @{Frequency=”Daily”; At=”17:00PM”}  if is there easier way to do it please share with me

Answer (score 2):

You answered your own question with:

> Register-ScheduleJob –Name “DHCPyedek” –FilePath “c:\powershell\scripts\dhcpYedek.ps1” –Trigger @{Frequency=”Daily”; At=”16:00PM”},Trigger @{Frequency=”Daily”; At=”17:00PM”} if is there easier way to do it please share with me – Ceyhun Tekin

That is the best way.

I feel compelled to post for you and other readers to learn how to *use the help system to get your answers quicker*.  Learning where to look and how to use the resources is also a skill.

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> get-help Register-ScheduledJob

NAME
    Register-ScheduledJob

SYNOPSIS
    Creates a new scheduled job.


SYNTAX
    Register-ScheduledJob [-Name] <String> [-ScriptBlock] <ScriptBlock> [-ArgumentList <Object[]>] [-Authentication 
    <AuthenticationMechanism>] [-Credential <PSCredential>] [-InitializationScript <ScriptBlock>] [-MaxResultCount <Int32>] 
    [-RunAs32] [-RunNow] [-ScheduledJobOption <ScheduledJobOptions>] [-Trigger <ScheduledJobTrigger[]>] [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] 
    [<CommonParameters>]
```

Notice that `Trigger` is:

```
[-Trigger <ScheduledJobTrigger[]>]
```

which is what you are now supplying (an array of `ScheduledJobTrigger`).

Don't forget that you can also use `-full` to see all the help available for a topic, usually with many examples.

```
get-help Register-ScheduledJob -full
```